# How to show transparent status in Ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar

I need to show transparent status bar in my Ionic app,

So I use https://github.com/ekuwang/cordova-plugin-statusbar plugin in my app, it transparent my app status bar but it looks like:

[image: Ionic App]

I want status bar transparent and my app look like:

[image] 
I google a lot but I don't any success to fix my issue. Please help me.

Comment: What exactly you expect ? Post the any example ..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [showUnderStatusBar()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-full-screen/#showUnderStatusBar) function of [cordova-plugin-fullscreen plugin](https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen).

Ionic official documentation link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-full-screen/

**Installation**

Cordova:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fullscreen
```

PhoneGap:

```
phonegap local plugin add cordova-plugin-fullscreen
```

**Usage**:

```
AndroidFullScreen.showUnderStatusBar(successFunction, errorFunction);
```

Github link of plugin: https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen

Nice tutorial of Immersive apps: https://competenepal.com/immersive-android-application-in-ionic/

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a padding-top css property to your header or your whole view, so it's always displayed below the status bar.